# Does labelled data need to be marked as verified for YOLOv5

Tags: pytorch, vision, yolov5

I have a labelled dataset that I haven't exported yet. I can flag each image as verified. But do I need to do this or is it optional? I saw this option sync across several labelling software.

I've mostly labelled the dataset but I am scared that the images may be ignored if I don't self verify them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone confused in the future. No you do not have to!. Here is the definition I just found right after posting.

"The user can flag the image as verified, a green background will appear. This is used when creating a dataset automatically"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).